# QT serial device

Tags: c++, qt, at-command

I want to communicate trough UART with an AT command device using Qt creator. I don't have Qserial or sth and i need to open the serial connection as a file using QFile. I am able to send data and receive responses. However, when receiving, which is the best way to look for a response after i send a command? If i try to look after end of file, my app blocks. 
For now i use this code:

```
     while(file->IsReadeble()
     {
         file->readLine(buffer,1023);
     }
```

The problem is that this code waits even if there are no available bytes.

Thank you

Comment: You have to use a specific thread which block on `readLine`, when you receive something, emit a signal and retrieve it through a slot to analyze it and emit new events or modify some UI

Comment: Another option is using `file->handle()` and [QSocketNotifier](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsocketnotifier.html)

Comment: May be you can use `bytesAvailable()` to check if there is any data to read before call `readLine()`

Comment: @JMA Apparently `file->bytesAvailable()` is always 0

Comment: "I don't have Qserial or sth" `QFile` is used to access disk files, not serial ports. It won't work for serial devices. Why do you think you don't have `QSerialPort`? What Qt version are you using? The serial port module is reasonably easy to backport even if you're using an older Qt...

Comment: It wors ish but only method that works is readLine() which is ok but sometimes the module sends just a character. I don't have qserial because the actual distro that i am working on was not compiled to have qserial